# Is it Possible? when mouse hover on you tube video then play that video and when mouse hover off then stop video.Its look like facebook

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance, youtube

i need help for my site which i have add video on that site.check following link http://proudtobeawoman.in/ scroll that page you can see that video.I want that video is play when mouse hover and when mouse hover off then stop that video.So is it possible?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please check this: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Is it working fine? the below answer..

Answer (score 1):

Try using like this, This might help,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     var videoContainer = $('#videoContainer');

     videoContainer.on('mouseenter', function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          $(this).trigger('click');
     });

      videoContainer.on('mouseleave', function(){
         e.preventDefault();
         $(this).trigger('click');
      });
});
```